# Python Tkinter event x, y, xroot, yroot showing incorrect values

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter

I am trying to get the x and y coordinates of an event in python 3.5. When using mouse buttons, it works properly, but the keyboard buttons are outputting values that have nothing to do with where the pointer is. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*

t = Tk()

def test(event):
    print('event.x, event.y:', event.x, event.y)
    print('event.x_root, event.y_root:', event.x_root, event.y_root)

t.bind('<Button>', test)
t.bind('<KeyPress>', test)

t.mainloop()
```

I tried clicking the mouse buttons at random places on the window and here is the output:

```
event.x, event.y: 40 0
event.x_root, event.y_root: 42 808
event.x, event.y: 12 12
event.x_root, event.y_root: 339 491
event.x, event.y: 169 145
event.x_root, event.y_root: 496 624
event.x, event.y: 186 193
event.x_root, event.y_root: 513 672
```

I tried the same thing pressing keyboard buttons and here is the output:

```
event.x, event.y: -327 -479
event.x_root, event.y_root: 0 0
event.x, event.y: -327 -479
event.x_root, event.y_root: 0 0
event.x, event.y: -327 -479
event.x_root, event.y_root: 0 0
event.x, event.y: -327 -479
event.x_root, event.y_root: 0 0
event.x, event.y: -327 -479
event.x_root, event.y_root: 0 0
```

I've noticed that the x_roots and y_roots are always 0, and the event.x's and event.y's only change when I move the window. Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: x, y:
The current mouse position, in pixels.

Does this help you? x_root, y_root:
The current mouse position relative to the upper left corner of the screen, in pixels. Taken from [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: @CoolCloud, Thank you, but that still doesn't explain why the x, y values are always negative and the x_root, y_root values are always 0, even when I move my pointer to a different place.

Comment: @Jacob your code works for me on Window10; Python 3.7

Comment: I think the prob when your pressing the keyboard was cause that you are pressing the keyboard and the mouse is at a constant position, it does not move?So at the time of press of a key, your mouse position is printed out

Comment: @CoolCloud Thank you again for trying to help, but I stated in my question that I moved the pointer at random positions before pressing the keys.

Comment: Youre code works absolutely fine for me and the problem is that, you misunderstood the concept and you are expecting a diff answer. Hope you got the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly because the mouse click has a related dynamic position, but your key click does not. If you want to get the position of the mouse you could constantly track the position of the mouse. The below code should do what you want.

```py
from tkinter import*

t = Tk()

pos_x = 0
pos_y = 0
r_pos_x = 0
r_pos_y = 0


def button(event):
    print('event.x, event.y:', event.x, event.y)
    print('event.x_root, event.y_root:', event.x_root, event.y_root)


def motion(event):
    global pos_x, pos_y, r_pos_x, r_pos_y
    pos_x = event.x
    pos_y = event.y
    r_pos_x = event.x_root
    r_pos_y = event.y_root


def key_press(_event):
    global pos_x, pos_y, r_pos_x, r_pos_y
    print('pos_x, pos_y:', pos_x, pos_y)
    print('r_pos_x, r_pos_y:', r_pos_x, r_pos_y)


t.bind('<Motion>', motion)
t.bind('<Button>', button)
t.bind('<KeyPress>', key_press)

t.mainloop()
```

As others suggested, I was able to find some methods that return the position of cursor at anytime. That would also work.

```py
def key_press(_event):
    global pos_x, pos_y, r_pos_x, r_pos_y
    print('pos_x, pos_y:', t.winfo_pointerx(), t.winfo_pointery())
```

Comment: Your code does nothing substantially different from above.

Comment: @Atlas435 Actually, it does. It creates variables that always track the position of the mouse, because apparently my keyboard can not. Also, it solved my problem.

Comment: _"If you want to get the position of the mouse you would have to constantly track the position of the mouse."_ - that's not true. Tkinter has methods for getting the coordinates on demand.

Comment: @Jacob If I didnt missed something the tkinter event manual page dosent get the position of a key. Read by yourself if you don't trust me. Do you do something diffrent in your orignal code? https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/event.htm#M39